# Type 'TestClassAttribute' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

After update the test project NuGet i got this error:

> The type 'TestClassAttribute' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Which one i should keep?

Comment: `TestClassAttribute` exists in both in order to allow for backward compatibility when switching to the newer framework.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I drop the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` from the unit test project references and it worked. It successfully compile and run my tests.

I couldn't find any documentation that supports this fix.

Comment: It says here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/ that Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework is the newer framework. It has the same API as Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, which can be safely removed from the references.

Comment: I drop it but the tests can't be discovered, even I install the `TestAdapter`.